# Emacs - No tabbable suggestions for init.el

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am fairly new to Emacs.

After opening `init.el` I would expect tab completion, just like in the minibuffer when doing `M-x` and typing part of a command and pressing `tab` to get the `*Completions*` window.

However, after entering part of a line:

```
(add-to-
```

and pressing `tab`, Emacs does nothing; it does not show the `*Completions*` window.

Is there a method of enabling `tab` completion when editing an `.el` file?

Comment: Your expectations seem wrong -- in Emacs-Lisp mode, the tab key is bound to `indent-for-tab-command` and the completion you seem to be looking for is on M-tab.  Are you asking how to rebind these keys, or are you just surprised?

Comment: Yes, I was actually suprised.  Since I am using Windows, `M-<tab>` actually switches the app, and `Esc-<tab>` would be too annoying to use.  I ended up using `company`.  However, just for future viewers of this question, how would you bind `<tab>` to the following function: do `indent-for-tab-command`, and if that didn't do anything, then do `completion-at-point`?

Comment: I can report that you quickly learn that esc is meta, to the point where you are not aware.  My muscle memory goes back almost 30 years by now but it's been that way for decades.  It's also decades since it was *actually* useful outside of a quirky special situation, but it's one thing less to worry about if I ever end up using a real VT102 terminal again.

Comment: Not sure how you would tell whether an indent actually "did anything". Comparing point before and after might be a good approximation, but I imagine there could be situations where it misses a "did".

Comment: `(let ((p) (point)) (indent-for-tab-command) (when (eq p (point)) (completion-at-point)))`

Comment: http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_tabs_space_indentation_setup.html - this link explains how to do it, but I am using `company-mode` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the TAB key to perform completion simply with

```
(setq tab-always-indent 'complete)
```

it won't prevent TAB from reindenting, tho: instead, it refines the behavior of TAB so that if TAB's reindentation has no effect (i.e. the line is already properly indented), it then tries to perform completion.  It should work in most major modes (as long as they provide the needed completion data via `completion-at-point-functions`), not just in Elisp.